# I'm trying to delete a record out of Core Data in xCode 8/Swift 3 & latest core data syntax

Tags: xcode, core-data

I'm trying to delete an entire record out of coreData. I've retrieved the data and placed it in an array for manipulation (I have another function that lets the user edit the data using this method and it works fine) But I can't figure out how to just delete the record. [.remove(at: index)] doesn't work and neither does the code below. I can set all the fields to empty but that's not what I want, I want the record gone completely.
I went through the solutions given for similar problems but to no avail

```
    @IBAction func Delete(_ sender: UIButton) { // The delete function

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DestinationsOne") 
    let context = appDelagate.persistentContainer.viewContext 

    var destArray = [DestinationsOne]() // The data array

    do {
        try destArray = context.fetch(request) as! [DestinationsOne]} //Fetching the data and placing it in the array
    catch{
        //error message
    }
        for index in (0..<destArray.count - 1){ //Go through the records
            if destArray[index].destID == IDTitle!{ //Picks the record to edit

            let object =  destArray[index]
                    context.delete(object
```

}
            `appDelagate.saveContext()
        }`

Comment: I could still use help with this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out. I'm posting the solution in case anyone else has the same question

```
func deleteRecords() -> Void { //The function to delete the record
                    let moc = getContext()
                    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DestinationsOne") 
                    let result = try? moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    let resultdata = result as! [DestinationsOne] // result as entity

                    for object in resultdata { // Go through the fetched result
                        if object.destID == self.IDTitle{ // If there is a match
                        moc.delete(object) // delete the object
                        }
                    }
                    do {
                        try moc.save() // Save the delete action
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    } catch {

                    }

                }
                func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext { 
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate 
                    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext 
                }

                 deleteRecords() // Call the function
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not applying a predicate to search this particular record. It's much more efficient than looping through a huge list.

```
func deleteRecords() { //The function to delete the record
    let moc = getContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<DestinationsOne>(entityName: "DestinationsOne")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "destID == %@", self.IDTitle)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let resultdata = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest) // no type cast needed
        if let objectToDelete = resultdata.first {
            moc.delete(objectToDelete) // delete the object
            try moc.save() // Save the delete action
       }          
    } catch  {
        print("Could not save error: ", error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues with your code:

- viewContext should be treated as readonly - you should use `performBackgroundTask` for all changes to core-data
- You are fetching ALL of the entities and then then going through each one to find the one you want to delete.  It is a lot faster to have core-data only fetch the one you want.  You can do this by setting a predicate to the fetch request.
- Instead of displaying your records by doing a fetch and using the array as a model, it is better to use a NSFetchedResultsController to do the fetch and manage the results.  The fetchedResultsController will keep the data in sync when objects are changed, inserted or deleted. It also has delegate methods that will inform you when there are changes so you can update your view.
- remove `appDelagate.saveContext` from your project.  Apple's template code is wrong.  You should never be writing to the viewContext so you should never have a reason to save it.
- where is `IDTitle` being set? are you sure it is not nil?
- (minor) `for index in (0..<destArray.count - 1){` can be replaced with `for (index, element) in destArray.enumerated() {` which is clearer to read.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Code examples for your suggestions would be good. I'm new at this so without examples I don't know how to implement them. IDTitle is set automatically when the record is created so it can't be nil.